# how to separate a array and store in different array based on element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

i have this array

```
[
   "code:757786",
   "code:940568",
   "dev:P1e655f7431fce787",
   "dev:P06b19c6891673644_fe1d",
   "code:835130",
   "code:716967",
   "dev:P9b6fb5f078267bc6_fdb5",
   "dev:P0a951f6ab1ca70a4_fe58",
   "code:048889",
]
```

and i want to separate based on ":" so that code is one array and dev in other 
so far i have got this

```
              var dev = [];
              var code= [];


              for (var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
                    var tmp=obj[i].split(':');                                              

                    if (tmp[0]='dev'){
                      dev[i]=tmp[1];
                      console.log(dev[i]);

                      $("#main-content").append(dev[i]);
                    }
```

now in console log it is showing all the details

Comment: The compare operator issue ... the oldest issue in Javascript (and C and C++ and C# and Java and and and). It is `==` rather than `=`

Comment: @devnull thanks ,so silly of me to leave this point ,got it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On this line, you have an assignment `=` not a comparison `==`. By using the single `=`, you are assigning `dev` to `tmp[0]` and the condition will always evaluate to `true`, causing the if block to always enter.

```
if (tmp[0]='dev'){
//        ^ change to double ==
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
 var data = [
  "code:757786",
   "code:940568",
   "dev:P1e655f7431fce787",
   "dev:P06b19c6891673644_fe1d",
   "code:835130",
   "code:716967",
   "dev:P9b6fb5f078267bc6_fdb5",
   "dev:P0a951f6ab1ca70a4_fe58",
   "code:048889",
 ];
 var dev  = [], 
     code = [];

 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var value = data[i].split(':');
    if (value[0] === 'dev') {
        dev.push(value[1]);
        $("#main-content").append(value[1]);
    } else {
        code.push(value[1]); 
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

what about RegExp ? maybe with some more checks

```
var a =  [ "code:757786", "code:940568", "dev:P1e655f7431fce787",
    "dev:P06b19c6891673644_fe1d", "code:835130", "code:716967", 
    "dev:P9b6fb5f078267bc6_fdb5", "dev:P0a951f6ab1ca70a4_fe58", "code:048889"],

    res = {dev : [], code : []};
for(var i = 0, l = a.length, tmp; i < l; i++){
    tmp = a[i].match(/^(dev|code):(.*)/);

    !!tmp && res[tmp[1]].push(tmp[2]);
}
console.debug(res);
```